# Need to do Ranking on a measured column in Direct Query mode. Is it possible?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Need to do Ranking on a measured column in Direct Query mode. Is it possible? I tried with below, but getting error "Function RANKX is not supported in Direct Query mode".

```
Rank = IF (
       HASONEVALUE ( Table_Name[ColumnName for which Ranking is required] ), 
RANKX ( ALL ( Table_Name[ColumnName for which Ranking is required] ), [ColumnName on which Ranking is required])
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you checked this:

go to file->options and settings -> options
under direct query, select "allow unrestricted measures"

Another approach, try the TOPN filtering for rank in visualizations.

Regards,